# How to know when you've reached enough resistance for a battery?

Tags: batteries

Let's say I have a 1.5 V AA battery. If I connect its terminals together, that creates a short circuit which could make the battery catch fire.

How do I know I've added enough resistance to the circuit so that the battery is safe to use?

Comment: You know rated current and rated voltage of the battery. "Enough resistance" will be equal to rated voltage/rated current.

Comment: Search for clues https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=aa+rated+current

Comment: If you simply add enough resistance not to overcurrent a battery, you have a quite nonspecific heater.  Is there something in particular you'd like to heat?

Answer (score 0):

A 1hr discharge is safe so Vbat/mAh=R but  at this current the 20 hr ___ mA rate may only be 50% for alkaline and 75% for Lithium (ballpark.) Where [watts] P =V^2/R, so as you reduce R and increase V/R=I[Amps] the self heating raises the battery temperature. If warm only after a few minutes, it's OK.but if it gets warm in seconds, not OK. –

Thus a 2Ah AA battery @ 1.5V can support 1.5/2= 0.75 Ohm for 30 minutes maybe.. check datasheet

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What datasheet?

Comment: The one you locate for your battery on the OEM website. What battery?